# Blank screen after phone call

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have written a game app which is in the final stages of testing. I am now checking it can recover from a variety of pause/resume events. All is working fine on my google nexus, but on my samsung galaxy Y, if a phone call comes in during gameplay, then when the call ends, the game screen is black. The game has not crashed, the sounds are still playing and if I press the menu button I see the menus appear - I can even select "about" and then see a dialog window appear and make it disappear again by clicking ok. I can even complete the game (blind) and see the end of game dialog appear correctly. There are no errors reported in logcat. If I run the program in the debugger, I can see the program repeatedly stepping through all the drawing routines and finally call unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas).

The graphics are being drawn in their own separate thread.

What kind of things could be preventing the display of my graphics?

Comment: Try repainting your canvas or whatever you've used in `onResume()`

Comment: `The graphics are being drawn in their own separate thread.` that could be the problem, graphics are only supposed to be drawn from the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an instance of setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); in my program. As soon as this was removed the problems disappeared. I confess I don't understand how this prevented graphics from being drawn or why the graphics work perfectly up until the phone call comes in.